# JS, expressJS, sequelize, postgres etc

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

So hello guys, first of all, wish you all the best for holidays - if u reading this between holidays haha.

I have a problem, in part of this code I can't get the output - value to proceed to the next part of code.

```
//add a gig
router.post('/add', (req, res) =>{

  let = {company_name, activity, description, contact_email, place_municipalities} = req.body;
  let errors = [];
console.log(place_municipalities)


//validate fields
  if(!company_name){
    errors.push({text: "Molim Vas dodajte naslov"});
  }
  if(!activity){
    errors.push({text: "Please add some technologies"});
  }
  if(!description){
    errors.push({text: "Molim Vas ispunite opis"});
  }
  if(!contact_email){
    errors.push({text: "Molim Vas da dodate kontakt email"});
  }
  if(!place_municipalities){
    errors.push({text: "Molimo Vas da izaberete općinu"});
  }

  //check for errors
  if(errors.length > 0){
    res.render('add', {
      errors,
        company_name, activity, description, contact_email, place_municipalities
    });
  //}else{
    //if(!budget){
      //budget = 'Nepoznat';
    //}else{
      //budget = `¢${budget}`;
    //}
    //make  lowercase and remove space after comma
    //activity = activity.toLowerCase().replace(/, /g, ',');
  //insert into table
  Gig.create({
    company_name, activity, description, contact_email, place_municipalities
  })

  .then(gig => res.redirect('/gigs'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
```

Where is console.log(place_municipalities) I can get value, but somewhere between lines it just gives me `original: { error: null value in column "place_municipalities" violates not-null constraint`

I'm not capable to debug this because I just starting to code, and I must finish it soon, can someone find what slowing me down? 
Thanks, regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `}else{`, I was accidentally commented to '}else{

Answer (score 0):

In your `router.post` method, I thing you are passing null value to `Gig.create` which is causing the error. You can try the following to ensure that you don't pass null to the `Gig.create`

```
let {company_name, activity, description, contact_email, place_municipalities} = req.body;
place_municipalities = place_municipalities ? place_municipalities : "";
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: tried that before, again same problem ` error: null value in column "place_municipalities" violates not-null constraint` Thanks sir.

Comment: @PetarBabić Can you share the schema of Gig?

Comment: ```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

const Gig = db.define('gig',{
  company_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },

  activity: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },

  description: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },

  contact_email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },

  place_municipalities: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },

})
module.exports = Gig;
```
Link of shema on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/J6Bs3km7
Here is it sir

Comment: @PetarBabić Answer updated! If you still face the same issue then kindly share the error stack

Comment: Now it continues to load the page and in the console, I get this output: https://pastebin.com/ua9WM2VP @Muhammad you bro have patience with people..

Comment: @PetarBabić can you share the code that how you are calling this method?

Comment: That would be this: https://pastebin.com/6pey95es , add.handlebars, From line 40

Comment: Try by commenting out this line `<option class="select-input" id="place_municipalities"  name="place_municipalities" for="place_municipalities" value="pusi_ga">native select element</option>` in `HTML`

Comment: Same as before, same output in the console, I think I need value= for sure, but I'm not sure where to put id, name, for..

Comment: Answer Updated! Try it now.

Comment: The error changed this time. It is now something like: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` I cann't help you without error stack

Comment: Sir, are you sure that error persists because of this line
`  let = {company_name, activity, description, contact_email, place_municipalities} = req.body;`
Because I can get output after that line, but anything after `//validate fields` comment is suspicious to me. Thanks for your help sir!